# Gauss-Seidel Method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, gauss

I am trying to implement the Gauss-Seidel method in MATLAB. But there are two major mistakes in my code, and I could not fix them:

1. My code converges very well on small matrices, but it never converges on large matrices.
2. The code makes redundant iterations. How can I prevent from redundant iterations?

[Gauss-Seidel Method on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Seidel_method).

```
N=5;
A=rand(N,N);
b=rand(N,1);
x = zeros(N,1);
sum = 0;
xold = x;
tic
for n_iter=1:1000
    for i = 1:N
        for j = 1:N
            if (j ~= i)
                sum = sum + (A(i,j)/A(i,i)) * xold(j);
            else
                continue;
            end
        end
        x(i) = -sum + b(i)/A(i,i);
        sum = 0;
    end
    if(abs(x(i)-xold(j))<0.001)
        break;
    end
    xold = x;
end
gs_time=toc;
prompt1='Gauss-Seidel Method Time';
prompt2='x Matrix';
disp(prompt2);
disp(x);
disp(prompt1);
disp(gs_time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, a generality. The *Gauß-Seidel* and *Jacobi methods* only apply to **diagonally dominant matrices**, not generic random ones. So to get correct test examples, you need to actually constructively ensure that condition, for instance via

```
A = rand(N,N)+N*eye(N)
```

or similar.

> Else the method will diverge towards infinity in some or all components.

---

Now to some other strangeness in your implementation. What does

```
if(abs(x(i)-xold(j))<0.001)
```

mean? Note that this instruction is *outside the loops* where `i` and `j` are the iteration variables, so potentially, the index values are *undefined*. By inertia they will accidentally both have the value `N`, so this criterion makes at least a little sense.

What you want to test is some norm of the difference of the vectors as a whole, thus using `sum(abs(x-xold))/N` or `max(abs(x-xold))`. On the right side you might want to multiply with the same norm construction applied to `x` so that the test is for the relative error, taking the scale of the problem into account.

---

By the instructions in the given code, you are implementing the Jacobi iteration, computing all the updates first and then advancing the iteration vector. For the Gauß-Seidel variant you would need to replace the single components in-place, so that newly computed values are immediately used.

---

Also, you could shorten/simplify the inner loop

```
xold = x;
for i = 1:N
    sum = b(i);
    for j = 1:N
        if (j ~= i)
            sum = sum - A(i,j) * x(j);
        end
    end
    x(i) = sum/A(i,i);
end
err = norm(x-xold)
```

or even shorter using the language features of matlab

```
xold = x
for i = 1:N
    J = [1:(i-1) (i+1):N];
    x(i) = ( b(i) - A(i,J)*x(J) )/A(i,i);
end   
err = norm(x-xold)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%Gauss-seidal method for three equations
clc;
x1=0;
x2=0;
x3=0;
m=input('Enter number of iteration');
for i=1:1:m
    x1(i+1)=(-0.01-0.52*x2(i)-x3(i))/0.3
    x2(i+1)=0.67-1.9*x3(i)-0.5*x1(i+1)
    x3(i+1)=(0.44-0.1*x1(i+1)-0.3*x2(i+1))/0.5
    er1=abs((x1(i+1)-x1(i))/x1(i+1))*100
    er2=abs((x2(i+1)-x2(i))/x2(i+1))*100
    er3=abs((x3(i+1)-x3(i))/x3(i+1))*100

    if er1<=0.01
       er2<=0.01
       er3<=0.01
        break;
    end
end
```